# Trouble while installing redis-server

Tags: ubuntu, apt, redis, dependencies

So for some reason it seems that the installation of the redis-server that was serving the sidekiq on one of my machines got removed (How does that happen?). I assume this because commands like which redis give blank likes.

I tried reinstalling with apt-get install and apt-get -f install but it keeps giving me this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
redis-server : Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~) but 1.7~precise1~ppa1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm unsure of how to correct this. Any help woudld be great.

Thanks!

Comment: have you upgraded your system or add new repository to sources list? also try apt-get install --reinstall

Answer (score 1):

Your list of package sources are screwed up.  You've added "conflicting" repositories, where some packages require newer dependencies than what is available in the rest of your repositories.

Here's the least-horrible way to fix it:

1. Run `apt-cache policy redis-server`.  This should produce a list of different versions of the `redis-server` package that could be installed.
2. Find the entry in the list that matches the `Candidate` version that is given at the top.  Immediately below that there will be a URL and a few other words.
3. Find the same line in your list of package sources (it'll either be in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, or a file in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`).  Delete that line, or at least comment it out by putting a `#` at the beginning of the line.
4. Run `apt-get update`
5. Try to install `redis-server` again.  If `apt-get` still gives you a similar error, then repeat the above instructions to remove *that* conflicting repository as well.

Eventually you'll have gotten rid of all the repositories which conflict with the running system, and you can continue on with your day.